# Can intellisense match words from the middle?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I'm learning a new API which has a LOT of properties.  I'd rather not scroll through a giant list if I have a general idea of what I'm looking for.

As an example, let's say I am putting in a telerik:GridBoundColumn tag, and I want that one property that lets me define a css class.  I've forgotten that it's called ItemStyle-CssClass so I start by typing css and hit Ctrl-space.  I get nothing useful.

Is there a way to tell intellisense to look for matches in the middle of a property name, not just at the beginning?  Is there a VS2008 plugin that can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know VS2100 can do that. Since MS presented that as an improvement, it's not present on previous versions :-)

Not 100% sure but probably [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) offers that intellisense feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Object Browser.  There is a search box in it.  You can have it search through all components in your solution or a specific set.  Spend some time messing around with it and see if it helps.